# Call to undefined function Illuminate\Encryption\openssl_cipher_iv_length()

Tags: php, laravel, openssl

Недавно потребовалось настроить сервер wamp для развертывания проекта на laravel. Но встретился вот с такой ошибкой *Call to undefined function Illuminate\Encryption\openssl_cipher_iv_length()* . Перерыл кучу информации - все говорят, что нужно убрать комментарий в php.ini. Сделал - не пашет(. Ещё вроде как должен быть какой то файлик php.ini в c:/windows, но у меня там такого нет.

HELP кто встречался с такой проблемой!

Проект без проблем запускается из phpstrom, а вот когда пытаюсь попасть на localhost, то получаю указанную выше ошибку.

Comment: попробуйте заного запустить `composer install ` или же `composer update`

Comment: Проблема осталась. Хотя перед выполнением composer install написал такие вещи: Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update. Это нормально?

Comment: А сервер то перегружали ?

Comment: ага, вот сейчас ещё раз перезагрузил

Comment: Файлик php_openssl.dll есть физически вообще?

Comment: Да, в нужном месте(на сколько я понял) - в папке wamp64\bin\php\php7.1.9\ext. У меня там только 3 папки с разными версиями php и в каждой этот dll есть.

Comment: посмотрите здесь, возможно это поможет решить вашу проблему
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/call-to-undefined-function-illuminateencryptionopenssl-cipher-iv-length?page=1

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку, но поверьте, я блог(который Вы скинули) помню лучше, чем дату своего рождения)

Comment: Вопросы закрыт. Мало ли кто прочитает: не понял как в конечном итоге всё заработало, перекопал php.ini и каким-то волшебством получилось выполнить задачу.

Comment: такой же трабл! куда "копать" ?

Comment: решение здесь  https://www.marathon-studios.com/blog/solved-laravel-5-error-undefined-function-illuminateencryptionopenssl_cipher_iv_length/             переустановка php

Answer (score 1):

Для тех кто ищет ответ. 
Для меня сработало, мой конфиг windows 10 x64.
Заменил интерпретатор PHP. т.е. Установил OpenServer. 
Затем прописал в переменную Path путь до директории C:\OSPanel\modules\php\PHP_7.2
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ещё раз повторю до директории! не до php.exe или ещё куда...
Подобная проблема была со снифером в phpstorm, по тому же принципу и здесь, - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fbCXYVEIxpA&t=131s